# How to escape the # (hash/pound) sign in SVN file names in linux bash

Tags: bash, svn, escaping, special-characters, filenames

If I name my file or directory using the # (pound/hash) sign, SVN treats it as if it's commented out and ignores it.

(see more [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.confarea.html), under *Configuration and the Windows Registry*)

How can I stop SVN from ignoring it?

If I create a file called `#aaa#` and run `svn status`. I expect to see `#aaa#` listed as untracked, but it's not displayed.

Comment: What svn client are you using? `svn add '#foo'` works for me with svn 1.7.20 on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an OS issue.

Linux treats # (hash/pound) signs as special characters and therefore they are ignore. This doesn't happen in windows.

If you run `svn add \#aaa#`, it will be added to the tracked list and you can then see it if you run `svn status`.

Comment: It's the shell (probably bash) that treats "#" specially rather than the OS.  The "#" character is used to start a comment, which causes the rest of the line to be ignored.  The same thing would happen on Windows if using bash (e.g., via Cygwin) instead of cmd.exe.